# Can we write data from DB2 and Oracle to CSV file in such a way that for datatype like BLOB, CLOB it should be empty string?

Tags: oracle, csv, db2, export, blob

I need a query for db2 and oracle which can be used for exporting data into CSV files and for datatype like BLOB, CLOB it will have an empty string.

eg:
Table-->

col1(char),col2 (blob),clo3 (date)

video_1,blob, '1998-05-02'

csv file --->

col1,col2,col3

"video_1","",'1998-05-02'

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just do `select col1, null, col3` instead of `select col1, col2, col3`?

Comment: Hi Alex, I am new to databases, I have to export more than 80 tables and these tables have a good number of columns also, checking for each table and putting null for blob columns will not do. I need something like " SELECT * FROM TABLE EXCEPT DATATYPE IN ('BLOB', 'CLOB')". I am also using python for writing it to CSV.

Comment: That syntax doesn't exist; you would need to use dynamic SQL - which might not be a bad choice. But for Oracle at least you could consider using the SQLcl client with `set sqlformat csv`, which would produce `"video_1","(BLOB)","1998-05-02"` - not exactly what you want, but you could then distinguish actually-null values. No idea about DB2 though.

Answer (score 0):

You may generate the corresponding statements dynamically to execute them later in Db2.
Below is an example for 2 system tables `SYSIBM.SYSTABLES` and `SYSIBM.SYSTABLESPACES`.
You may run it as is to get 2 `EXPORT` commands with the corresponding `SELECT` statements.
The output can be used as is to execute it as a script of commands with the Db2 Command Line Processor (`db2 -tf out_file.sql` in a session with a database connection established). If you comment out the string with `EXPORT`, you may get pure corresponding `SELECT` statements to use them with some another tool capable to save the result of an arbitrary `SELECT` statement to a CSV file (as the Db2 `EXPORT` command does it).

```
SELECT 
  'EXPORT TO ' || RTRIM (T.TABSCHEMA) || '.' || T.TABNAME || '.csv OF DEL'
||' SELECT ' || LISTAGG (CASE WHEN C.TYPENAME LIKE '%LOB' THEN '''''' ELSE '"' || C.COLNAME || '"' END, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C.COLNO)
||' FROM "' || T.TABSCHEMA || '"."' || T.TABNAME || '";'
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES T 
JOIN SYSCAT.COLUMNS C ON C.TABSCHEMA = T.TABSCHEMA  AND C.TABNAME = T.TABNAME 
WHERE T.TABSCHEMA = 'SYSIBM' AND T.TABNAME IN ('SYSTABLES', 'SYSTABLESPACES')
GROUP BY T.TABSCHEMA, T.TABNAME
```